# User authentication login error

Tags: windows, authentication, microstrategy

In my work we have users who access a Web based tool called Microstrategy that serves different reports from different projects. Users are added to various groups in the Developer tool by importing them from the selected domain they are on into a specific group that gives them access to only the project > report they require. Most users come from one main central domain, some others are still on old domains.

I am currently involved with admin on this system and I am experiencing a problem I cannot get to the bottom of. I think they problem lies in no man's land, I don't know if it is a problem with network, domain, or something else?

Most users will be set up with authenticated login, meaning that when they click on the respective link for their report they are logged straight in using their windows credentials.

In this particular case however the user does not seem to be able to login, but can get in by manually typing their username in (username and password) to access.

I'm not sure what the problem is, why it won't authenticate automatically like most of the others do? I don't know if this makes any difference but when I RDP into the machine I cannot see the C drive due to 'admin restrictions on effect on this pc'.

I don't know what this restriction is and if it is a symptom or related to the login problem. Is there a way of fault finding this?

Thanks

Andrew

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this partly depends on the version of MicroStrategy you are using.

Forget about RDP to the server, you won't need that.

Assuming you have access to edit and change users with the Developer tool, open Developer.
In the tree on the left,

- open the "project source" (the top level of the tree)
- then Administration
- then User Manager
- then find the user, most likely within one of the groups you have set up
- right click on the user and choose Edit
- go to the Authentication section

There's a few relevant things here.

- Is the user linked to a windows user? (they should be for the access you want)
- Is the tickbox ticked "user cannot use standard authentication to logon"
  You probably don't want to allow that if the standard at your workplace is auto login